# Clone a RHEL 5 box into a smaller disk

Tags: redhat, rhel5, cloning

I'm trying to clone a physical RHEL 5 box into VMware. That box contains a 1 TB disk which is hardly used (80 GB). Thus I want the new virtual machine to have a 100 GB disk instead of wasting a new 1 TB.

The free disk space in the VM host is only 200 GB, not 1 TB. Therefore, the Vmware converter client cannot run successfully -- it requires 1 TB of free disk space in the VMware host.

Firstly I tried `mondo-mindi` software to backup/restore because it does not need to power off the physical box and it allows create ISO images, but after two weeks of failed attempts I got fed up and I eventually quit.

Do you know any software to clone a RHEL 5 server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: RHEL 5 is end of support in less than a year. If I were you, I'd spend my efforts just building a new box in RHEL 7 and migrating the application/data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GParted to resize your RHEL5's partitions then use 'Volume Based Cloning' in Vmware's converter.

This should work unless you have reason to keep your physical RHEL completely as is...

Answer (score 0):

Try CloneZilla (http://clonezilla.org), it can clone partitions to smaller destinations.